# Pass SauceLabs username/accesskey into DriverOptions class

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, saucelabs

I am trying to send selenium tests to saucelabs using the `DriverOptions` class.  According to [this](https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/Selenium+W3C+Capabilities+Support+-+Beta#SeleniumW3CCapabilitiesSupport-Beta-sauce:options) link, you need a sauce:options configuration, and according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50488115/how-do-i-use-mutablecapabilities-with-selenium-for-c) post a Dictionary will do. Here is my setup:

```
DriverOptions options = new ChromeOptions
{
    PlatformName = "Windows 10",
    BrowserVersion = "latest"
};
IDictionary<string, string> sauceOptions = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "username", SauceUsername },
    { "accessKey", SauceAccessKey },
    { "name", TestContext.TestName },
    { "seleniumVersion", "3.11.0" }
};
options.AddAdditionalCapability("sauce:options", sauceOptions);
_driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://@ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub"),
    options.ToCapabilities(), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(600));
```

I get a `WebDriverException` on the `RemoteWebDriver`init, saying `Misconfigured -- Sauce Labs Authentication Error.  You used username 'None' and access key 'None' to authenticate`.  This is weird because

1. I am given back the desired caps I used, which were:

   The following desired capabilities were received:
   {'browserName': 'chrome',
    'browserVersion': 'latest',
    'goog:chromeOptions': {'sauce:options': {'accessKey': 'XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX163edf42',
                                             'name': 'DriverOptionsTest',
                                             'seleniumVersion': '3.11.0',
                                             'username': 'kroe761'}},
   'platformName': 'Windows 10'}

The last few digits of my accesskey are right and that is my username, so clearly I sent the correct credentials

2. If I remove the dictionary and pass the username and accesskey directly into the RemoteDriver uri (`http://{SauceUsername}:{SauceAccessKey}@ondemand`...) it works,  However, I can't pass in any other sauce options.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `AddAdditionalCapability` overload that takes three arguments, not two. This tells the `ChromeOptions` instance to add the dictionary to the top-level of the JSON payload, rather than as part of the `goog:chromeOptions` property. Here is what that would look like:

```
// Note, you must use the specific class here, rather than the
// base class, as the base class does not have the proper method
// overload. Also, the UseSpecCompliantProtocol property is required.
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions
{
    PlatformName = "Windows 10",
    BrowserVersion = "latest",
    UseSpecCompliantProtocol = true
};
Dictionary<string, object> sauceOptions = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { "username", SauceUsername },
    { "accessKey", SauceAccessKey },
    { "name", TestContext.TestName },
    { "seleniumVersion", "3.11.0" }
};
options.AddAdditionalCapability("sauce:options", sauceOptions, true);
_driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub"),
    options.ToCapabilities(), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(600));
```

Comment: That threw the exception `ChromeOptionsTest threw exception: 
System.InvalidOperationException: session not created: Missing or invalid capabilities`

Comment: @kroe761 I've updated the code snippet. You shouldn't use `IDictionary<string, string>` but rather `Dictionary<string, object>`. Nevertheless, it would be interesting to note the payload sent to the remote end at SauceLabs. Is there anything beyond what you've listed there in the exception message? I'm quite sure the syntax of the code above is correct.

Comment: Thanks for your help - I copied your code and it threw the same error.  This is the full `Message: Test method SauceDemo.UnitTest.DriverOptionsTest_Chrome threw exception: 
System.InvalidOperationException: session not created: Missing or invalid capabilities
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.45.615291 (ec3682e3c9061c10f26ea9e5cdcf3c53f3f74387),platform=Windows NT 10.0.10586 x86_64) (SessionNotCreated)`..........

Comment: .........and when I debug the `options` instance I get this: `{{
  "browserName": "chrome",
  "browserVersion": "latest",
  "platformName": "Windows 10",
  "goog:chromeOptions": {},
  "sauce:options": {
    "username": "kroe761",
    "accessKey": "--------",
    "name": "DriverOptionsTest_Chrome",
    "seleniumVersion": "3.11.0"
  }
}}`

Comment: I see where the disconnect is. You need to set the `UseSpecCompliantProtocol` property in the options class. https://github.com/saucelabs-training/w3c-examples/blob/master/csharp/NUnitExamples.cs

Comment: @jimevans example should work. It works for me and I have a similar one here: https://github.com/saucelabs-training/w3c-examples/blob/master/csharp/NUnitExamples.cs